# I want to access a data continuoulsy. Means on each change the API should give me updated data

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-repositories

For now, I am working on like button. So, database is storing person who liked. Upon liking it will try to add user's email to db and return updated liker(for unlike it will remove from db). so, I can print in angular using array.length to see how many person liked

But, now what I want is when another person like it. In my browser I also get updated like counter. For that what I can do is request the spring boot API in each second. But, that is not recommended I think. What can I do so I will get liker list from spring boot to angular continuously?

Comment: This requires a different approach, using either WebSockets or Server Sent Events. The question is too broad though to go further into detail than that.

Comment: ok. The question is broad as I have no idea with what to proceed and this much info you gave is enough to get an idea. I will see both socket and server sent event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket.io might be what you're looking for. It's a real time library that performs the trick through a web socket. You can trigger events from server-side and make you client listen to them with a callback, and update your view consequently.

https://socket.io/

Comment: I see. I will go through socket programming. Is it ok to use websocket programming only for like button for webapp where no other part of code need socket. Means is it recommended in my situation?

Comment: Since the library is relatively lightweight (less than lodash for instance), I would say that it's a fair strategy. Having post requests every seconds might be far more resource consuming, since you will have to do it for every post on your page. You should have less code write using it though :)